# How to check what the current users role is

Tags: c#, asp.net

How do I check in C# what the current users role is, and print it to the screen.

Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You can use [`Roles.GetRolesForUser()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h930x07.aspx) method to get all the rols user belong to . use it like this;

```
string[] rolesuserbelongto = Roles.GetRolesForUser();
```

you will have all roles in string array.

you can even pass a UserName as a parameter to get the roles for that particular User like this:

```
string[] rolesuserbelongto = Roles.GetRolesForUser("Shekhar_Pro");
```

Comment: What namespace has to be added in order to have "Roles" class?

Comment: @Ixtlan - 
using System.Web.Security;

Answer (score 7):

The most general method is to get an [IPrinciple](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx) and then call IsInRole() on it. How you get the Principle denpends on your runtime environment. This example works well for apps running under the user's account.

Example:

```
    static void PrintIsInAdministrators()
    {
        // There are many ways to get a principle... this is one.
        System.Security.Principal.IPrincipal principle = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal;
        bool isInRole = principle.IsInRole("MyDomain\\MyRole");
        Console.WriteLine("I {0} an Admin", isInRole ? "am" : "am not");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`Roles.GetRolesForUser();` gave me the error `The Role Manager feature has not been enabled`.

If you are using `ASP.NET Identity UserManager` you can get it like this:

```
var userManager = Request.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>();

var roles = userManager.GetRoles(User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

If you have changed key for user from Guid to Int for example use this code:

```
var roles = userManager.GetRoles(User.Identity.GetUserId<int>());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] userroles = Roles.GetRolesForUser(Page.User.Identity.Name);
foreach(var role in userroles)
{
Response.Write(role);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### This is what you are looking for:

```
@if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (User.IsInRole("Admin"))
    {
      <h1> I only show this text to admin users </h1>
    }
}
```

**Note:** You can check the roles defined in your `AccountController.cs` file, if you have one implemented.

Answer (score 0):

You can use user manager for that purpose:

```
 var userRoles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
```

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure of you question.

You can do:

```
this.User.IsInRole();
//loop and check whether the user is in your role.
```

`this` would correspond to a [page class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx), so you can write the above code only inside a page and `this.User` returns an [IPrincipal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.principal.iprincipal.aspx).